# How to force canonical URL in Meteor hosted on Bluemix?

Tags: meteor, dns, ibm-cloud

I deployed a Meteor app to IBM Bluemix which created an address like `myapp.mybluemix.net`.

Inside Bluemix panel, since we have our own custom domain, I registered it with the address `myapp.com` and then I created three routes: `myapp.mybluemix.net`, `myapp.com` and `www.myapp.com`. I also created an enviroment variable `ROOT_URL = 'www.myapp.com'`, since we want the **www.** version to be used instead of the naked domain.

Inside the DNS provider panel, I put a CNAME record as `www.myapp.com CNAME myapp.mybluemix.net` and a A record as `myapp.com A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` (pointing to the public IP of Bluemix host).

With all these, my app was opening well, but with duplicated URLs. Then I discovered the [Canonical package](https://atmospherejs.com/wizonesolutions/canonical) and republished my app with it included hoping to solve the canonical need.

Unfortunately, all requests both to `myapp.com` and `www.myapp.com` redirects to `myapp.mybluemix.net`!

I can't see what configuration is causing this problem. What of the described steps I went wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following steps helped me configure canonical URL :

**1)** Install the canonical meteor package

**2)** Configure two routes to your application (naked and www subdomain)

[image]

**3)** Set CF environment variable : `cf set-env leadershipboard ROOT_URL "http://www.vamsee.ml"`

**4)** Configure DNS server CNAME to route traffic to Bluemix application : 
[image]

**5)** Use slightly modified meteor buildpack : https://github.com/JProgrammer/cf-meteor-buildpack

Hope it helps.

Comment: Really thank you for the steps provided, helped me a lot! In the end I believe the real problem was really with the Buildpack not setting the `ROOT_URL`. Anyway, I tried following all the steps but needed two things different: *1.* I needed to keep `myapp.mybluemix.net` as a third route (without it I received a 404 error); *2.* My DNS provider doesn't let CNAME for naked domains, so I also created an A record pointing to the app's IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I think that very probably the error is not with the custom domain configuration (which is working fine because according to your description all the routes are resolved correctly) but with the www redirect you are doing to make the www.myapp.com the default host.

If you provide more details about you have implemented it we could help you in finding out what could be wrong

Comment: The redirection from the naked domain to the *www* subdomain was implemented inside the [Canonical package](https://atmospherejs.com/wizonesolutions/canonical) that I cited. Looking at the source code (https://github.com/project-ricochet/meteor-canonical/blob/master/canonical_server.js), it does a permanent `301 redirect` to the `ROOT_URL` if the `request.headers.host` is not equals to it. Since my `ROOT_URL` is already `www.myapp.com`, what's could wrong?

Comment: I wonder if the buildpack not able to read ROOT_URL ? see : https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-meteor-buildpack/pull/12 , Can you try with this buildpack :https://github.com/JProgrammer/cf-meteor-buildpack

Comment: I wonder if, as told by @vmovva it cannot read the ROOT_URL, or you setting is valid and the ROOT_URL is set to http://myapp.mybluemix.net
It seems to behave like you have set ROOT_URL to http://myapp.mybluemix.net
Could you show how you set the ROOT_URL variable?